# Querying dataset by conditions in nested JSONB document

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a fairly simple table in PostgreSQL database (v 9.6):

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (id serial, data jsonb);
```

Here is an example of JSONB document that is stored in data column:

```
[{ key: 'foo', value: 100 }, { key: 'bar', value: 5 }, { key: 'baz', value: 10 }]
```

I am trying to write a select that will return every row where conditions in JSONB document are met and select only specified nested documents; i.e. for every row where `foo` is greater than `X` return all nested documents that have `baz` as key.

So far I've came with a query like this but it does not work — it is returning 0 records.

```
SELECT id
  FROM foobar
 WHERE (data->>'key' = 'foo' AND (data->>'value')::numeric > 5)
    OR (data->>'key' = 'bar' AND (data->>'value')::numeric < 10)
```

Also it would be great if anyone knows how to optimize the final query. Thanks!

Comment: Use `>=` and `<=`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for every row where foo is greater than X return all nested documents that have baz as key.

Use `jsonb_array_elements(data)` twice. The first for comparing the value with the key `foo` and the second to find object with the key `baz`:

```
with foobar(id, data) as (
values
(1, 
'[
    { "key": "foo", "value": 100 }, 
    { "key": "bar", "value": 5 }, 
    { "key": "baz", "value": 10 }
]'::jsonb)
)

select id, value_baz
from foobar,
jsonb_array_elements(data) el_foo(value_foo),
jsonb_array_elements(data) el_baz(value_baz)
where value_foo->>'key' = 'foo' and (value_foo->>'value')::numeric > 5
and value_baz->>'key' = 'baz';

 id |          value_baz          
----+-----------------------------
  1 | {"key": "baz", "value": 10}
(1 row)
```

---

The format of your json column is rather strange. I see no reason to use a json array here. You can store the same information in a simple form like this:

```
'{ "foo": 100, "bar": 5, "baz": 10 }'
```

In this case your query might be as simple as:

```
with foobar(id, data) as (
values
(1, '{ "foo": 100, "bar": 5, "baz": 10 }'::jsonb)
)

select id, data->'baz' as baz
from foobar
where (data->>'foo')::numeric > 5;

 id | baz 
----+-----
  1 | 10
(1 row)
```

Comment: Yeah second solution is much better; I've tried that initially and achieved ~200ms selects with gin index over data (I do have a fairly larger dataset). First option just does not work on my dataset — is it too large and selects take over 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with:

- unnesting your JSON array into elements (using [the `jsonb_array_elements` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html))
- [`HAVING bool_or(...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) to ensure at least one of the elements has `foo` as key and `value` greater than `5`
- [aggregate filtered](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES): *only* those sub-documents, which has `bar` as key

---

```
SELECT     id, jsonb_agg(e) FILTER (WHERE e ->> 'key' = 'bar')
FROM       foobar
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(data) e
WHERE      data @> '[{"key":"foo"},{"key":"bar"}]'
GROUP BY   id
HAVING     bool_or(e ->> 'key' = 'foo' AND e -> 'value' > '5')
```

*Notes*:

- `e -> 'value' > '5'` will compare the `value` JSON property with the JSON value `5`, which works perfectly, if you use numbers in your JSON documents. If that's not the case (i.e. you also have JSON strings, which you want to handle as numbers), use a `CAST`, like `(e ->> 'value')::numeric > 5`
- `WHERE data @> '[{"key":"foo"},{"key":"bar"}]'` is completely optional. I included here, because that's the most you can squeeze out from a [GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) (on the `jsonb` column; if you have any). But that will be almost useless, if those keys are on almost every row in your table.
- Unfortunately every solution will require the use of `jsonb_array_elements()`, which defeats the use cases of JSON indexes. With your current design, a sequential table scan is unavoidable (unless the predicate above can actually filter out a lot of rows).

http://rextester.com/XCPB80482